# How to determine the shard Id for a particular key in redis?

Tags: python, redis

I have a number of Redis shards, and am trying to retrieve the shard details given a key with the Redis Python client. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why the downvote on this? It's useful to say what's wrong with the question and suggest how it could be improved rather than simply downvoting.

Comment: Why do you need the information? If we understand the reasons, we may be able to provide an even better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I have a lot of shards and there are clusters for each of these shards. I would like to make sure the key that belongs to a particular shard is also available in the cluster of the respective shard.

Comment: Please update the OP with any code you have tried to accomplish this, any errors received and your the problem you are trying to solve. I get a strong feeling that this could be an XY problem.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`CLUSTER KEYSLOT`](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-keyslot) command?

Comment: @IanAuld I thought the same thing.